# database design for a e-commerce website

Tags: mysql, e-commerce

i m making a e commerce website and i am little confused about the manufacturers table . i have a category table in which suppose i have taken as a example 
2 values "mobile phones and ipods" and the sub category table contains the category and subcategory value now the sub category has 2 values such as "gsm" and "cdma" and according to their category value "1" which is from the category table value "mobile phones". now how would i make manufacturers table according to that the same brands would be used by many categories . can any one help me in making a neat manufacturers table .  the idea i had was like i would enter the category name in manufacturers table and put the value as 1 for used 0 for not used

manufacturers table:

```
id  manufacturer_name  
1   Apple              
2   Htc
```

Category

```
id  item_category
1   Mobile Phones
2   Ipods
```

Sub Category

```
id  item_category  Sub Category
1   1              Gsm
2   1              Cdma
```

my manufacturers table IDEA

```
id  manufacturer_name  Mobile Phones    Ipod's
1   Apple                   1             1
2   Htc                     1             0
```

the idea seems ok but i really dnt know if there is a better solution . well i case of very large number of categories suppose 30 + categories then its not possible to write each category name in manufacturers table and set their value to 1 or 0 . can anyone suggest me some better idea???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of your idea, create a manufacturer_category_mapping table that joins one to the other like this:

```
manufacturer_id  category_id
1                1
1                2
2                1
```

So each row is literally a mapping between a manufacturer and a category.

This table could then have a composite key of both manufacturer_id and category_id, this would prevent you from mapping a manufacturer to the same category twice.

Hope this helps.

To answer the comment, 5 manufacturer_id with category_id  of 1 would look like this:

```
manufacturer_id  category_id
10               1
11               1
12               1
13               1
14               1
```

Comment: thanks for suggestion friend , but suppose we have 5 manufacturer_id with category_id "1" then ?

Comment: Updated my question - this is an acceptable way to implement a database. You're only storing the numbers, and your table doesn't have to change every time to introduce a new category.

Comment: simple sober awesome .thanks for the solution @greg84 really didn't came to my mind . thanks for helping out friend

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a product table.  Then tie each product to a category / sub-category and tie the manufacturers to the products they make with a many to many relationship.

```
Manufacturer
- ManufacturerID
- ManufacturerName
- etc..

Product
- ProductID
- ProductName
- etc...

Manufacturer_Product
- ManufacturerID
- ProductID


select m.ManufacturerName, p.ProductName
from dbo.Manufacturer m
join dbo.Manufacturer_Product mp on mp.ManufacturerID = m.ManufacturerID
join dbo.Product p on p.ProductID = mp.ProductID
```

Comment: hello chris i really didnt get what u wanted to say . ManufacturerID is  ManufacturerName? or what is lil confusing can u clear it out ?

Comment: I added the manufacturer table.  It's using a foreign key in the link table 'Manufacturer_Product' to determine which manufacturers make which products.